# WP Output logged in user's first name and last name

Tags: wordpress

I am currently making a Wordpress theme. In the "Log In" button, I want the user's name to show up if he is connected. If not, than a certain text will be shown.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to display the username:

```
if(is_user_logged_in())
{
   get_currentuserinfo();
   echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login .;
} else {
  echo "log in";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to display logged in user's `first name and last name`:--

```
if(is_user_logged_in())
{
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $first_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', true);
    $last_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_name', true);

    echo $first_name ." ". $last_name;
}
else
{
    echo "Your Certain Text.";
}
```